# Top bar Region with logo and social share buttons with search bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Can anyone help me to correct the code to align the logo ,social share buttons with search bar in the same line in top bar of bootstrap as the image attached below[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYAAY.png)
 and the corresponding menu navigation bar with bootstrap.
My Code is attached below,i am able to get the desired structure but cant apply proper css to it.

```
<div class="top-bar">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div><!-- logo-end -->
    </div>
</div>
<!---Social Icons--> 
<div class="col-sm-8 " align="right">

    <div class="social">
        <ul class="social-share">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <!---Search Screen-->
        <div class="search">
            <form role="form">
            <div class="searchtop">
                <input type="text" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type your search here...">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </div>
            </form>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Thank You.

Comment: you need to show what you desire vs what you got right now... and the css you tried to get the desired result

Comment: I would suggest go to the codepen and replicate the results.. then ask the question with the link... something like this: http://codepen.io/kazx/pen/ryjqwV

Comment: Hi @Ahmad here is the codepen link can you please review and help me to get it http://codepen.io/miststudent2011/pen/KWaExW or https://jsfiddle.net/z65pthxq/

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 " align="right">
    <div class="social">
        <span><a href="#">facebook</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">twitter</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">linkedin</a></span> 
        <span><a href="#">pinterest</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">instagram</a></span>

    <!---Search Screen-->

       <span>
            <input type="text" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type your search here...">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>            
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just replace the header and search bar code with the code that I told earlier. Add required classes for it to look good.

Comment: do you want me to add a fiddle and help you out?

Comment: please help me with fiddle if you got time. :-)

Comment: Here it is. Just a gist of how the code looks.  https://jsfiddle.net/shivatinu/n1m6cm7w/

Answer (score 0):

As show by your sample image you wanted to align the logo on left side while social media icons, search & navbar on the right side. The social media icons being on the top row.

There are few methods to do this. I essentially used this approach:

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">Logo</div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="col-md-12">Social-Icons & Search-Bar</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">Nav-Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The snippet below is not going to show the accurate result cause of width limitations. But the HTML structure is correct. For results see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/kazx/pen/zZNVQa)

```css
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'open_sansregular', sans-serif;
  color:#4e4e4e;
  line-height: 22px;
}
/* Background image for header */
.header-bg {
 margin-top: -5px;
 background-image:url("../images/banner.png");
 
}

/* Top region begins */
.social-share {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin-right:2px;
}
ul.social-share li {
    display: inline-block;
} 
.social {
    text-align: right;
 margin-top:30px;
}
ul.social-share li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #808080;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 14px;
}
ul.social-share li a:hover {
background:#1C83C6;
}
.input-group{
margin-top:30px;
margin-right:-40px;
}
.input-group-addon{
color:#1C83C6;
}


/* Top region Ends */

/* Menu region Begins */

.navbar-custom { 
   margin-top:8px;
   background-color:none;
}

.nav.navbar-nav li .color{
   color: red;
 }
.nav.navbar-nav li  a:hover {
   background-color : #F36C35;
   color: blue;
 } 
 ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>A Pen by Ahmad</title>


  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div class="header-bg">
      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <!--Header-->



          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 navbar-brand">
              <a href="index.html"><img src="http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingGreenReal/200x200_OilPaintingGreenReal_55ddf783e44e4c54b5cec77bc164c1ad.jpg" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <!---Social Icons-->
            <div class="col-md-9 socialMedia-navBar">
              <div class="socialMedia-serachbar">
                <div class="col-md-6 social visible-lg visible-md">
                  <ul class="social-share">
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li></ul>

                </div>
                <!--Search Bar-->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your search here" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon ">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </span>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <!--Navigation Bar-->
              <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                      </button>

                  </div>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" aria-expanded="true">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle color" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">RESUME <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="dropdown-submenu">

                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level 1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Second level 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Second level 3</a></li>
                            </ul>

                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>

                        </ul>

                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle color" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">CAREER EXPLORATION<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level 1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Second level 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Second level 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="color" href="#">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle color" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">COVER LETTERS<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Hover me for more options</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level 1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Second level 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Second level 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="color" href="#">MEET THE TEAM</a></li>
                      <li><a class="color" href="#">CONTINUING EDUCATION</a></li>
                      <li><a class="color" href="#">EMPLOYERS</a></li>
                    </ul>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

      </header>
      </div>
  </body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>


</body>

</html>
```